# Spinner OnItemSelectedListener in Custom adapter Listview call recursively without selecting any item

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-spinner, android-adapter

I have custom adapter list view with two spinner view.

Each spinner has a background process. On initializing, the spinner view.OnItemSelectedListener is recursively called unnecessarily without any external input to the listener

Class file

```
public class ClientListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter  {
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<GetClientListDetail> data = null;
ArrayList<GetClientListDetail> temp = null;
String ID, str;
Typeface typeface;
PopupWindow cp;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

String[] Status1 = new String[] { "Waiting", "Away","No Show"};

String[] Status2 = new String[] { "In Service",
        "Generate Bill", "Completed" };

SpinnerAdapterlist TherapistAdapter = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> StatusAdapter = null;

ArrayList<GetTherapistProperties> TherapistList ;


private LayoutInflater inflater;

RemoveClient RC;
ChangeStatus CS;
ChangeTherapist CT;

ClientListHolder holder ;
int _therapistID;


GetClientListDetail ap;

GetTherapistProperties tp;

boolean networkavailable=false;




public ClientListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        ArrayList<GetClientListDetail> gld, ArrayList<GetTherapistProperties> therapislist) {
    super();
    this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = gld;
    this.mGalleryCount1 = gld.size();
    this.mGalleryCount2=gld.size();
    this.TherapistList=therapislist;


    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    Resources res = context.getResources();

    TherapistAdapter = new SpinnerAdapterlist(context,
            R.layout.spinnerlayout, TherapistList);

    StatusAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Status1);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return data.size();
}

@Override
public GetClientListDetail getItem(int position) {

    return data.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {

    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;



    if (row == null) {

        holder = new ClientListHolder();


        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder.tv_no = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_no);
        holder.tv_name = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_name);
        holder.tv_status = (Spinner) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_status);
        holder.tv_therapist = (Spinner) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_therapist);



        holder.iv_edit=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_clientwaitlayout_edit);

        holder.iv_action = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_clientwaitlayout_action);
        holder.tv_unchange_therapist=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_unchange_name);
        holder.tv_unchange_status=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_unchange_status);



        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ClientListHolder) row.getTag();
    }


    holder.tv_therapist.setAdapter(TherapistAdapter);
    holder.tv_status.setAdapter(StatusAdapter);


    ap = data.get(position);
    tp=TherapistList.get(position);

    holder.tv_name.setText(ap.getCLDName());
    holder.tv_no.setText(ap.getCLDNo());


    if(ap.getCLDStatus().equals("1") ){
        Log.d("LOOP","Sub If condition");

        holder.tv_therapist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv_unchange_therapist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tv_unchange_status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.iv_action.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.iv_edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        try {
            for(int x=0;x<TherapistList.size();x++){
                if(ap.getCLDTherapist().equals(TherapistList.get(x).getID())){

                    holder.tv_therapist.setSelection(x);

                }else{  

                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            holder.tv_status.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(ap.getCLDStatus()) - 1);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            holder.tv_status.setSelection(0);
        }


    }else if(ap.getCLDStatus().equals("2") | ap.getCLDStatus().equals("6")){

        holder.tv_therapist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv_unchange_therapist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tv_unchange_status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.iv_action.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.iv_edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        try {
            for(int x=0;x<TherapistList.size();x++){
                if(ap.getCLDTherapist().equals(TherapistList.get(x).getID())){

                    holder.tv_therapist.setSelection(x);

                }else{  

                }
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            if(ap.getCLDStatus().equals("2")){
                holder.tv_status.setSelection(1);
            }else{
                holder.tv_status.setSelection(2);   
            }
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            holder.tv_status.setSelection(0);
        }


    }else{

        holder.tv_therapist.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tv_status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.tv_unchange_therapist.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.tv_unchange_status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.iv_action.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.iv_edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        for(int y=0;y<TherapistList.size();y++){
            if(ap.getCLDTherapist().equals(TherapistList.get(y).getID())){

                holder.tv_unchange_therapist.setText(TherapistList.get(y).getName());

                break;
            }else{

                holder.tv_unchange_therapist.setText("Not Available");
            } 
        }
        if (ap.getCLDStatus().equals("2")) {

            holder.tv_unchange_status.setText(Status1[1]);

        } else if (ap.getCLDStatus().equals("3")) {

            holder.tv_unchange_status.setText(Status2[0]);

        } else if (ap.getCLDStatus().equals("4")) {
            holder.tv_unchange_status.setText(Status2[1]);

        } else if (ap.getCLDStatus().equals("5")) {
            holder.tv_unchange_status.setText(Status2[2]);

        } else if (ap.getCLDStatus().equals("6")) {

            holder.tv_unchange_status.setText(Status1[2]);
        }

    }



    holder.tv_therapist.setTag(ap.getCLDClientID());

    holder.tv_status.setTag(ap.getCLDClientID()); 

    holder.iv_edit.setTag(ap.getCLDClientID());

    holder.iv_action.setTag(ap.getCLDClientID());

    holder.iv_action.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try { 
                ImageView b = (ImageView) v;
                String id = b.getTag().toString();
                Log.d("ID is", id);

                Intent CDV=new Intent(context, TabSample.class);
                CDV.putExtra("ID",  id);
                //CDV.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
                //context.startActivity(CDV);
                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(CDV,5);

                try {
                    Log.d("POSITION", "" + position + " "
                            + data.get(position).getCLDClientID());
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });

    holder.tv_status
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        int id=arg2+1;


                        try {
                            try {


                                CS=new ChangeStatus();
                                CS.setClientID(data.get(position).getCLDClientID());
                                CS.setSalonID("1");
                                if(id==3){
                                    CS.setStatus("6");
                                }else{
                                    CS.setStatus(String.valueOf(id));
                                }


                                new LoadChangeStatus().execute();
                            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });


    holder.tv_therapist
    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try { 

                    try {
                        Spinner sp = (Spinner) arg0;

                        String str = sp.getTag().toString();

                        TextView th_id=(TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.spnradptno);

                        CT=new ChangeTherapist();
                        CT.setClientID(str);
                        CT.setSalonID("1");
                        CT.setTherapist(th_id.getText().toString());

                        new LoadChangeTherapist().execute();

                        Log.d("SPR TXT", th_id.getText().toString()+" "+position+" "+str);

                    } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
                        Log.d("Error in spinner",e.toString());
                    } 

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.d("Error2 in spinner",e.toString());
                }


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d("Nothing","Selected");
        }
    });




    holder.iv_edit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            try { 
                ImageView b = (ImageView) v;
                String id = b.getTag().toString();
                Log.d("ID is", id);

                Intent CDV=new Intent(context, TabSample.class);
                CDV.putExtra("ID",  id);


                ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(CDV,5);


                try {
                    Log.d("POSITION", "" + position + " "
                            + data.get(position).getCLDClientID());
                } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });





    return row;
}

static class ClientListHolder {

    TextView tv_no;
    TextView tv_name;
    Spinner tv_therapist;
    Spinner tv_status;
    ImageView iv_action;

    ImageView iv_edit;
    TextView tv_unchange_therapist;
    TextView tv_unchange_status;

}

public class LoadChangeStatus extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    // Before running code in the separate thread
    int LoadChangeStatus= 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Create a new progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        // Set the progress dialog to display a horizontal progress bar
        // progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        // Set the dialog title to 'Loading...'
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        // Set the dialog message to 'Loading application View, please
        // wait...'
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait...");
        // This dialog can't be canceled by pressing the back key
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // This dialog isn't indeterminate
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // The maximum number of items is 100

        // Set the current progress to zero

        // Display the progress dialog
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    // The code to be executed in a background thread.
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try {
            // temp.clear();
            networkavailable=new Network().isNetworkAvailable(context);
            if(networkavailable){
                temp = CS.Change_Status(CS, context);   
                LoadChangeStatus=1;
            }else{
                LoadChangeStatus=2;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("ERROR", "LoadChangeStatus backgroung");
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Update the progress
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // set the current progress of the progress dialog

    }

    // after executing the code in the thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // close the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        if(LoadChangeStatus==1){
            try {
                data.clear();
                data.addAll(temp);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }else if(LoadChangeStatus==2){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Changing Status Failed. Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}

public class LoadChangeTherapist extends
        AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    // Before running code in the separate thread
    int LoadChangeTherapist = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Create a new progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        // Set the progress dialog to display a horizontal progress bar
        // progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        // Set the dialog title to 'Loading...'
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        // Set the dialog message to 'Loading application View, please
        // wait...'
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait...");
        // This dialog can't be canceled by pressing the back key
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // This dialog isn't indeterminate
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // The maximum number of items is 100

        // Set the current progress to zero

        // Display the progress dialog
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    // The code to be executed in a background thread.
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        try {
            // temp.clear();
            networkavailable=new Network().isNetworkAvailable(context);
            if(networkavailable){
                temp = CT.Get_Change_Therapist(CT, context);    
                LoadChangeTherapist=1;
            }else{
                LoadChangeTherapist=2;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.d("ERROR", "LoadChangeStatus backgroung");
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Update the progress
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // set the current progress of the progress dialog

    }

    // after executing the code in the thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // close the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (LoadChangeTherapist == 1) {
            try {
                data.clear();
                data.addAll(temp);
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (LoadChangeTherapist == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Removing Client Failed. Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}

public class LoadRemoveClient extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    // Before running code in the separate thread
    int LoadRemoveClient = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Create a new progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        // Set the progress dialog to display a horizontal progress bar
        // progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        // Set the dialog title to 'Loading...'
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        // Set the dialog message to 'Loading application View, please
        // wait...'
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait...");
        // This dialog can't be canceled by pressing the back key
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // This dialog isn't indeterminate
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // The maximum number of items is 100

        // Set the current progress to zero

        // Display the progress dialog
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    // The code to be executed in a background thread.
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        Log.d("ERROR", "LoadRemoveClient backgroung");
        try {
            networkavailable=new Network().isNetworkAvailable(context);
            if(networkavailable){
                temp = RC.Get_Client_List_Detail(RC, context);  
                LoadRemoveClient=1;
            }else{
                LoadRemoveClient=2;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Update the progress
    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // set the current progress of the progress dialog

    }

    // after executing the code in the thread
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        // close the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (LoadRemoveClient == 1) {
            try {
                data.clear();
                data.addAll(temp);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (LoadRemoveClient == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Removing Client Failed. Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}

}
```

How to avoid unnecessarily calling of view.OnItemSelectedListener of spinner view On initializing custom adapter list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop or avoid calling of onItemSelectedListener on initialization. But you can prevent this by declare an integer and set value as 0 and while on calling getview method, check the integer with size of data(Your array list size).if the integer is less than the size than increment the integer value else do your background work. But it's not right way to do because when you scroll the listview the same problem rise again. You do this if you have fixed array list size. It is better to use AutoCompleteTextView instead of SpinnerView.

Comment: But i want only spinner view in the listview. User only can change it but autocomplete textview allow user to edit it. It doesn't work for my question.

Comment: No you can do the same with AutoCompleteTextview. setEditable to false and setBackground to it as spinnerview like. Then implement onTouchListener to it. Here you show the list with showDropDown() method then you can select the item in the list with onItemClickListener and do the background process in it.

Comment: Okay i ll try it and get you back.

Answer (score 0):

It gets called for the selection of the first item(Kind of default value).

Try one thing don't set adapter to spinner if row!=null for ex:

```
 if (row == null) {

        holder = new ClientListHolder();


        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder.tv_no = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_no);
        holder.tv_name = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_name);
        holder.tv_status = (Spinner) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_status);
        holder.tv_therapist = (Spinner) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_therapist);



        holder.iv_edit=(ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.btn_clientwaitlayout_edit);

        holder.iv_action = (ImageView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.btn_clientwaitlayout_action);
        holder.tv_unchange_therapist=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_unchange_name);
        holder.tv_unchange_status=(TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tv_clientwaitlayout_unchange_status);

        holder.tv_therapist.setAdapter(TherapistAdapter);
        holder.tv_status.setAdapter(StatusAdapter);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ClientListHolder) row.getTag();
    }
```

Comment: thank you fro reply. But it called recursively. Is any way to avoid calling first item selection?

Comment: i already tried with the same code like you posted it did not work